# How to get a Model in function of controller in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to delete item. For that I'm passing id of item from html form to controller function destroy(). i.e, `public function destroy (Request $request, Item $item){...}`. `Item` is a model. But I'm not getting model in function as I have checked by this line, `dd($item)`. It contains `null attribute`. It is sure that `$item` in function parameters `contains the value of product id` i.e,`public function destroy (Request $request, $item){...}`. But when I'm using Model in parameters, there is nothing in attribute array. (Checked by `dd($item)`). I'm also implementing `Policy in Model`. In short, I'm following [this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate). But I can't perform delete operation as it contains model with no attributes. If anyone knows the answer, answer will be appreciated. Here is my code.

**Model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['col1', 'col2'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user');
    }
}
```

**Policy**

```
namespace App\Policies;
use App\User;
use App\Item;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ItemPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function destroy(User $user, Item $item)
    {
        return $user->id === $item->user;
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
protected $policies = ['App\Client' => 'App\Policies\ClientPolicy'];
```

**ItemController**

```
use App\Item;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\ItemRepository;

public function destroy(Request $request, Item $item)
{
    dd($item);   //This shows empty attribute in item
    $this->authorize('destroy', $item);

    // Delete The Task...
    $client->delete();
    return view('/clients');
}
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{ url('items/'.$item->id) }}" method="POST">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
    <button type="submit" id="delete-item-{{ $item->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', function ()
{
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function ()
{
    Route::auth();
    Route::resource('items', 'ItemController');
});
```

If I'm right, then there is no any issue related to Policy and View as I'm getting value of item ID in $item.

Comment: Can you post the code for your routes as well as the form as well?

Comment: I'm getting control of destroy() method of ItemController even with value of $item. So there should no any issue in those scripts. But still as per your request, I'm posting.

Comment: Okay from the form you are just passing the id of the $item as a parameter, so when in your ItemController you try to access (Model) $item it shows null, because the parameter contains just the id and not the full model.

Comment: So change your destroy function to accept $id, public function destroy(Request $request, $id){ //check to see if the item exists in db $item = \Item::find($id); $this->authorize('destroy, $item); ...}

Comment: post your routes file please

Comment: Where are the routes for your ItemController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer just rename your route resource to singular:

```
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');
```

What you want is [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding) and for you to achieve that the easiest way is running `php artisan routes:list`

This is a small example for you to understand, my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('list', 'ListingController');
```

When I run `php artisan routes:list` I get this:

```
+--------+-----------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI              | Name         | Action                                         | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                |              | Closure                                        |            |
|        | POST      | list             | list.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ListingController@store   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | list             | list.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ListingController@index   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | list/create      | list.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ListingController@create  |            |
|        | DELETE    | list/{list}      | list.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ListingController@destroy |            |
|        | PUT|PATCH | list/{list}      | list.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ListingController@update  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | list/{list}      | list.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ListingController@show    |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | list/{list}/edit | list.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ListingController@edit    |            |
+--------+-----------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

So has you can see my **URI** the name of my parameters are **{list}** for route model binding to work, your variable name on your controller must be exactly the same.

So you either rename your routes, or on your controller instead of using `Item $item`, you have to use `Item $items`